# Kotlin socket property getter should I check for exception?

Tags: android, sockets, kotlin

I'm writing an Android bluetooth client application in Kotlin. Now I'm trying to get `OutputStream` from a connected socket.
When writing in Java, I have to check for `IOException`:

```java
OutputStream stream;
try
{
    stream = socket.getOutputStream();
}
catch(IOException e)
{ ... }
```

But in Kotlin, it seems that I can directly get the object through getters

```kotlin
val streamOut : OutputStream = socket.outputStream
```

The question is should I check for `IOExecption` as well? Or is the outputstream already set in the `socket.connect()` step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is very strict about exceptions. Whenever you write a code that could throw an exception, you need to either catch it or mark your own method with `throws`. Kotlin does not require this, you are not enforced to catch exceptions, but that doesn't mean it will auto-magically handle errors for you or something. `socket.outputStream` may throw an exception, so you need to be prepared for such a situation. If you omit `catch {}` block, then in the case of an error, it will propagate through the call stack.